# likelihood in EM algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Regarding the EM algorithm.
If I understand correctly, the likelihood is obtained in the E-step (for instance in the Baum–Welch algorithm the likelihood can be obtained form the forward-backward procedure).
However, the final step in each EM-iteration is the M-step. That means the likelihood computed in the step k, actually "belongs" to the parameters of step (k-1). Is that really so, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The EM algorithm aims at, given a model, finding the parameters of the model that maximize the likelihood of the data.

The focus is on the parameters and not on the likelihood value.

From my understanding, the E-step is meant to compute the expected value of the log-likelihood function. Which in practise, mostly consists in computing the values needed for the M-step, using the current parameters values. In the M-step, you get the parameters that maximize the likelihood (or its lower bound). You can subsequently compute the likelihood value with the new parameters.

Are you working with HMMs? If yes, I can specify the quantities computed at each step.

Hope this can help! :)